# Will using a console command disable any further achievements?

Tags: subnautica

I just wondered if using a [console command](http://subnautica.wikia.com/wiki/Debug_Console_Commands) will disable further achievements or lead to any other side effects?

The wiki only states that using a command will "impair your Subnautica experience" which is not quite helpful in this case.

Comment: There are only three achievements in the game so far.  They can be completed fairly fast also.  One is to simply submit a feedback report, one is dive to 40m (pretty shallow considering how deep some parts of the game are), and the other is to craft an oxygen tank.  The only thing that may slow you down is getting supplies for the oxygen tank.

Comment: Yes I know there are only three achievements. But the game is currently in early access so I expect more achievements to pop up later. Therefore I asked if using a console command will block achievements later.

Answer (score 1):

The wiki says that it might impair your Subnautica experience because of the higher possibility to encounter bugs while using (or abusing) the console.

As far as I know, there is no achievement block, since you're using the debug console.

Also, I bet that there's a command to unlock achievements, but I might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

In release 1.0 there are now 17 achievements.  Using the console will disable further achievements from that point onwards, but you keep the ones you have so far.  I don't know if the ability to get achievements resets to 'able' if you start a new game and don't use the console as I used the console for the first time after getting them all.